# PDF programming in Python:Set limits on number of times the PDF can be printed

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation

PDF allows you to set permissions such as a document can be printed just once or just 10 times etc. I believe Adobe Acrobat Professional allows you to set those.

My question is it possible to do so in Python programmatically? If so how?

Comment: If you have a Mac, then you can print a PDF once as another PDF. I am sure that Windows and Linux allow something like that as well. This is the same problem as with protecting DVDs, etc. You could in the past open up the analog TV and intercept very clean signal. With digital TV you can probably intercept video with something that pretends to be another monitor. Un-protecting a PDF would not require nearly as much effort - simply send it to a "printer" and intercept and reconstruct it then.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to restrict the number of times a PDF file can be printed (outside Adobe LiveCycle or some other very controlled hosted solution).  Although there is lots of discussion about this e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/37216/restrict-print-copies-on-a-pdf

If you have other info please indicate a reference.

There is an open source pypdf module https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/ But no hints there about print restriction.

Comment: if you have a Mac, then you can print a PDF once as another PDF, and all this protection would have gone out of the window.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like ReportLab can allow you to set whether a PDF can be printed.  See page 58 of the [manual](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf).  I don't know if it can also let you control the number of prints.

Comment: That's not an option within PDF.  "printable or not" is.  So that won't work.